# How to flip axes and show it zoomed in for LineGraph MPAndroidchart

Tags: android-studio, mpandroidchart

I'm not sure how to flip the axes of my chart. Below is the code I'm using.
Please see also the picture on how it looks right now. Instead of drawing the data vertically I'd like to show it horizontally. It suppose to look like a stock chart because that is what it actually is. I'm using YQL to get the historical data of the symbol as Json format.

I also see the data is scooped in the whole screen. I'd like to see the last month for example and just allow the user to swipe to the right for more or just to zoom out.

I'd appreciate some help.

```
float vals=0;
            String[] resultStrs = new String[StockHistoryArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < StockHistoryArray.length(); i++) {


                JSONObject chartDataObj = StockHistoryArray.getJSONObject(i);

                yVals.add(new Entry(vals,(int) Float.parseFloat(chartDataObj.getString("Adj_Close")),i+1));

                xVals.add(i, String.valueOf(vals));

                vals++;

            }

           LineDataSet setting = new LineDataSet(yVals, "Stock Chart");


            ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new

            ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
            dataSets.add(setting);


            LineData data = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);


            lineChart.setData(data);


            Legend l = lineChart.getLegend();
            l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
            l.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            XAxis x1 = lineChart.getXAxis();
            x1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            x1.setDrawGridLines(false);
            x1.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);

            YAxis y1 = lineChart.getAxisLeft();
            y1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            y1.setAxisMaxValue(120f);
            y1.setDrawGridLines(true);

            return null;
```

Here is the screen shot after I run this code. It is one year history.

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQj79.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong in the following line.

```
yVals.add(new Entry(vals,(int) Float.parseFloat(chartDataObj.getString("Adj_Close")),i+1));
```

Use like this to draw the chart correctly

```
yVals.add(new Entry(entryVal,entryXIndex);
```

If your value in `chartDataObj.getString("Adj_Close")`

then you need to add like this
`yVals.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(chartDataObj.getString("Adj_Close")), i);`